# How to join two consecutive events?

Tags: sql

I have two tables, one with events and another with tracks, and I want to combine them together. In table events I have session_id, event_id, event_timestamp, product_id. In table tracks I have session_id, product_id, action, event_timestamp, track_id. In my final table I want to have session_id, event_id, event_timestamp, product_id and track_id. It doesn't look complicated, but the problem is that event_timestamp doesn't match in both tables, and one product_id can have multiple track_id. I have the following query, but is causing me duplicates.

```sql
SELECT
    distinct tr.session_id
    , tr.product_id::VARCHAR                       AS product_id
    , tr.track_id::VARCHAR                         AS track_id
    , me.action||'.'||me.category                  AS action_category
    , me.event_timestamp 
    , me.EVENT_ID       
FROM session_experiment se
INNER JOIN lyst_analytics.tracks tr                --this join will filter all the tracks and mobile events that are in the experiment
    ON se.session_id = tr.session_id
INNER JOIN CORE_APP.MOBILE_EVENTS me
    ON  me.session_id = se.session_id
    AND tr.product_id::VARCHAR = me.product_id
    AND tr.session_id = me.session_id
WHERE 1=1
    AND me.product_id IS NOT NULL
    AND COALESCE(DATE(tr.event_timestamp), DATE(me.event_timestamp)) > {{start_date}}
    AND COALESCE(DATE(tr.event_timestamp), DATE(me.event_timestamp)) <= {{end_date}}
    AND tr.event_timestamp > me.event_timestamp
    AND me.action||'.'||me.category
    IN ('clicked.add to bag', 'clicked.buy')
```

Comment: do a left join and convert the date using a datepart

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results for that sample data. It might also be helpful to specify your database system (I'm guessing PostgreSQL, but it helps to be explicit).